# Retrieving valueless data from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Being completely new to Firebase/JSON I'm a bit confused as to how I would retrieve 'base' data. 'Base' probably being the completely wrong syntax.

[image: **Firebase Database**]

How would I access/print the 'Places' if they don't have a value? When I give 'New York' a value, I can't add a child to it. So I'm confused how I would get that data?

**ViewController**

```
var ref: DatabaseReference?
var handle: DatabaseHandle?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    handle = ref?.child("Places/London/UK/Latitude").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let item = snapshot.value as? Double
            print(item)
    })
}
```

This prints the latitude fine (because it has a value). But what I want is a list of places - ie London, New York & Paris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Simple way to get List of your cities.

```
 handle = ref?.child("Places").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
       for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let key = snap.key
        let value = snap.value
        print("key = \(key))
    }
    })
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! So I'm creating a 'key' for each child under the "Places" key using the `.children` and `as! DataSnapshot` ? (It's all working perfectly, just want to make sure I can learn/understand the process!)